# Image Upload using Base64

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, extjs4, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image to JAVAServer, Following are the details :

I am using server : JAVA Spring with REST Services and Extjs 4.

I need to upload image using base64 to Server.

1. What are the best practices for uploading image to server ?
2. How to convert image to base64 string in extjs4 ?
3. How to submit form along with form data ?

With this I am able to hit server but every parameter is null i.e. no data is being transferred 
var form = Ext.getCmp('member_form').getForm();

```
if (form.isValid()) // Validation
{
// communicating with server for registering member info
form.submit({
url : '/my/Test',
// standardSubmit: true,
method : 'POST',
waitMsg : 'Registring...',
success : function(form, o) {
console.log(form);
msg('Success', 'Processed file "'+ o.result.file + '" on the server');
},
failure : function() {
alert('Registration failed...');
}
});
}
```

Please help me I am stucked at this point.

Comment: Have you set the form enctype to multipart form-data ?

Comment: yes I have already tried but the result was same .....

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading your image as any other file. Convert it on the server, it's straight forward. You cannot edit (convert to base64 in your case) a file in the browser while uploading it.

I ExtJs, you use the `Ext.form.field.File` to upload a file. I never tried personnaly, but have a look at [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File) an try the example.

Comment: Actually in extjs I am using Ajax request is that correct ? and I need to upload image some how but I dont know how to do it ? Please help me....

Comment: By using above request I am able to get request at server but everything in request is null that is the main problem I am facing

Comment: I completed my answer. Hope it helps.